# redirect to method if post type method receives get request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a post type

> ActionResult

method like below. If I try to visit that url, I mean put `get` request on that method, then I want it to redirect to another method. Is this possible?

I mean since this method only accepts post type request so if anyone send get request then it will just redirect to another controller/method. Ask question if you're confused.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I particulary liked the part "Ask question if you're confused." in this question.

Comment: Then hit up....funny boy! @hbulens

Comment: That's not how it works on SO. You should write your questions in such a way that there is no confusion possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement one handler to process [HttpGet].

Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Process()
{
    return RedirectIfGet();  //the specific process for the request type=GET
}
```